# Converting a column in a dataframe to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

Converting a date column in a dataframe and uploading it to google sheet is giving error as

The data is as below which is read from excel sheet

```
Account ID  Account Names   Account Owner   Account exit Date
111555777   Test 1          John Doe         11/29/11
222444555   Test 2          Doe John         6/28/11
```

I did convert the column to the string but it uploads the dates as string which I do not want.

```
df['Account End Date'] = df['Account End Date'].astype(str)
test1 = df.values
test2 = test1.tolist()
sheet.insert_rows(test2,2)
```

What do I need to do to have the format back as date.

Please help.

Comment: You have to show us your sample data. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you try df['date_col'] = df['date_col'].astype('str') before uploading to google sheet

Comment: @perpetualstudent, I did use that, the dates are going as string format in the google sheet, but I want it as date format in the google sheet as well

Comment: it seems google sheet API cannot handle datetime for now, so I'm afraid you'd have to change from string to datetime on google sheet